# How can I remove SGID bit only to files (excludig folders)?

Tags: bash, chmod

Unfortunately, I applied recursively SGID bit to my folder tree.
SGID got set to any files or directories, though I only wanted to set SGID bit to folders.
So I want to correct my mistake.

If I do a `chmod -R g-s *`  it will includes files and folders.

How can I remove SGID bit only to files in my folder recursively ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `find` in order to execute the command only for files:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod g-s {} \;
```

Comment: Great ! That works ! Could you just explain the last part with: {} \;

Comment: The braces tell the find command "put the results here" one-by-one.  The \; is an escaped semicolon that says "all done".  Good question, and good for you for wanting to understand how everything works before running a command.